# How can i apply @JsonSerialize annotation to a lib class property?

Tags: java, jackson, json-serialization

I'm using an external library in my project. One of it's models has a BigDecimal property, that requires a custom precision. If this model was mine, i would apply a @JsonSerialize annotation that uses custom serializer. But i can't modify sources of ext. lib...
Is there any way to apply it somehow?

Comment: Maybe [jackson-objectmapper-using-custom-serializers-and-deserializers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21706415/jackson-objectmapper-using-custom-serializers-and-deserializers) can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exactly for this use-case Jackson offers so-called mixins.
To illustrate how to use this let's walk through an example:

Suppose you have a library class (named `Model`) containing
a property of type `BigDecimal`.`

```
public class Model {

    private BigDecimal number;
    
    public BigDecimal getNumber() {
        return number;
    }
    
    public void setNumber(BigDecimal number) {
        this.number = number;
    }
}
```

Now, you cannot modify the source of the library class above.
But instead, you can write a class (let's call it `ModelMixin`)
which kind of mirrors the library class `Model` and
put any Jackson annotations there.
Especially you can specify your own serializer for
the `BigDecimal number` property.

```
public abstract class ModelMixin {

    @JsonSerialize(using = MyBigDecimalSerializer.class)
    private BigDecimal number;
}
```

The serializer might be as simple or sophisticated
as you need it. Here is a simple one which
chooses to write the `BigDecimal` as a JSON string.

```
public class MyBigDecimalSerializer extends JsonSerializer<BigDecimal> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(BigDecimal value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        gen.writeString(value.toString());
    }
}
```

Now you need to tell Jackson's `ObjectMapper`
to take the annotations from the `ModelMixin` class
and apply them to the`Model` class.
This is done by the [`addMixIn(Class,Class)` method](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#addMixIn(java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Class)).

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()
    .addMixIn(Model.class, ModelMixin.class);
    
Model model = new Model();
model.setNumber(BigDecimal.valueOf(123.456));
    
objectMapper.writeValue(System.out, model);
```

This writes the following JSON output:

```
{"number":"123.456"}
```