# Re-using Jackson ObjectMapper varying in registered serializer

Tags: java, jackson

I'm using Jackson's ObjectMapper in my Java Spring Boot project to perform read serialization of some data (various AJAX queries sent to service)

```
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        module.addDeserializer(Game.class, newGameDeserializer);
        objectMapper.registerModule(module);
```

But this 4-line code gets a bit repetitive here and there as I have a bunch of objects to serialize.

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        SimpleModule simpleModule = new SimpleModule();
        simpleModule.addSerializer(Serie.class, new SerieSerializer(Serie.class));
        objectMapper.registerModule(simpleModule);
```

What would be the best approach to change these 4-lines into a potentially reusable single line? I guess that static method to obtain ObjectMapper might not be the best idea.

```
    public static <T> ObjectMapper getObjectMapper(Class<? extends T> type, JsonSerializer<T> ser) {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        SimpleModule simpleModule = new SimpleModule();
        simpleModule.addSerializer(type, ser);
        objectMapper.registerModule(simpleModule);
        return objectMapper;
    }
```

What could be the best approach? Maybe creating separate classes (GameObjectMapper, SerieGameMapper) that extend ObjectMapper and contain these 4-line definitions, and then inject them using @Autowired annotation in the class where I need that? I haven't tried that yet but I feel like it makes no sense to keep spawning new ObjectMapper objects.

I've seen this question - [Using custom serializers / deserializers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21706415/jackson-objectmapper-using-custom-serializers-and-deserializers) - but I'm not sure if I need that much in my implementation.

Tried using static method, but I'm not really convinced since statics are not recommended, but I also do not think that doing "new ObjectMapper()" several times is a good idea.

Comment: You can create a utility class and define the function and call it wherever you need it.

Comment: make a @Configuration class which provides a configured Jackson objectmapper bean and autowire where required?

Comment: though, you have to remember, if you are doing any unwrapping or any sort of operations that would modify a specific object (ie with jackson mixins) it is always recommended to have a separate mapper for that. cuz it would affect the usual operations you do and you would get data you dont expect.